# The Diophantine equation $x^2 + py + a = 0$.

Tags: diophantine-equations

Let $p$ be an odd prime. Show that the Diophantine equation
$$x^2 + py + a = 0$$
with $\gcd(a, p) = 1$ has an integral solution if and only if $\left(\frac{-a}{p}\right) = 1$

Comment: @Marc: Dear Marc, Firstly, if $a = 0$ then gcd$(a,p) = p$, not $1$.  Secondly, $(-a/p)$ denotes the Legendre symbol, not the ratio.  In short, you comment isn't really on point.  Regards,

Comment: Dear bill, Why don't you begin by writing down the *definition* of $(-a/p) = 1$?  Regards,

Comment: I removed my comment, my apologies for the sloppy reading.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint for $(\Rightarrow)$:**

Suppose there is a solution $(x_{0},y_{0})$ to the equation. Then

$x_{0}^{2}=-py_{0}-a$

What is the reminder when the RHS is divided by $p$? 
Also, if $gcd(a,p)=1$, then what can be said about $-a$ being a quadratic residue $mod p$?

**Hint for $(\Leftarrow)$**:

Suppose $(-a/p)=1$ i.e. $x_{0}^{2}=-a+kp$ for some integers $x_{0}$ and $k$.

Can you then find an $y_{0}$ such that $(x_{0},y_{0})$ is a solution to the equation?